'UserTable' does not exist on type 'DrizzleTypeError<"Seems like the schema generic is missing - did you forget to add it to your DB type?">
I'm trying to learn Drizzle and I encounter this error when I tried to do a query, but when I run the code, I get this error

src/main.ts:7:35 - error TS2339: Property 'UserTable' does not exist
on type 'DrizzleTypeError<"Seems like the schema generic is missing -
did you forget to add it to your DB type?">'.

7     const result = await db.query.UserTable.findMany({
main.ts
import { db } from "./db/db";
import { UserTable } from "./db/schema/schema";
async function main(){

    const result = await db.query.UserTable.findMany({
        with: {
          name: true      
        },
      });

      console.log(result)
}

main()

schema.ts
export const UserTable = mysqlTable('users',{
    id: int('id').primaryKey().autoincrement(),
    name: varchar('name', {length: 255}).notNull(),
    age: int("age").notNull(),
    email: varchar("email", {length: 255}).notNull(), 
    roll: mysqlEnum('userRole',["ADMIN","BASIC"]).default("BASIC").notNull(),
})


You need to tell drizzle how your schema looks, the drizzle constructor looks like:
drizzle<typeof schema>(client: YourDbClient, config?: DrizzleConfig<typeof schema> | undefined): YourDbClient<typeof schema>

and DrizzleConfig takes a schema propriety, so you can try something like this:
import * as schema from "./schema"    

    
const db = drizzle(mysqlConnection, { schema }) // db will be typed as MySqlDatabase<typeof schema> now

If all your schema is in one file you should be able to simply import it like this. If you use multiple files in a schema directory, add an index.ts that exports everything like:
// index.ts
export * from './email_verification';
export * from './sessions';
export * from './user-passwords';
export * from './users';

Now you should be able to import it like above

Just use the small letter that's it...
here is the example
export const vendorStatusEnum = pgEnum("status", ["active", "suspended", "pending"]);

// make sure you put it like this way
status: vendorStatusEnum().notNull().default("pending"),


NOTE: make sure you export your pgEnum
https://github.com/drizzle-team/drizzle-orm/issues/646#issuecomment-2465651364
